# Hvfloat FULLPAGE problem

Tags: graphics, fullpage, hvfloat

At the end of the chapter, I would like to include a full-page illustration. For this purpose I use the hvfloat package with the FULLPAGE option.

Unfortunately, there is a narrow margin. How can I display the image correctly on the entire page.

I noticed that this code works fine in the TeXLive 2022 version (in Overleaf).

**Edit:**
This package works great, but in my case latest version has a problem with twosided documents.

I downloaded an older version of the package and placed the files in my working directory. It worked as a temporary solution.

https://tug.org/svn/texlive/branches/branch2022/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hvfloat/hvfloat.sty?revision=62886&view=co

https://tug.org/svn/texlive/branches/branch2022/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hvfloat/hvfloat-fps.sty?revision=62886&view=co

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

%\documentclass[twoside=true, mpinclude=true,  version=last, chapterprefix=true, numbers=noenddot, paper=b5, BCOR=12mm, DIV=9]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[twoside=true, mpinclude=true,  version=last, chapterprefix=true, numbers=noenddot, paper=b5, DIV=9]{scrbook}
\documentclass[twoside=true, mpinclude=true,  version=last, chapterprefix=true, numbers=noenddot, paper=b5]{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test 1}
\lipsum{5}
\hvFloat[FULLPAGE]{figure}{\includegraphics[FULLPAGE]{example-image-a}}{caption1}{caption1a}
\chapter{Test 2}
\lipsum{2}
\hvFloat[FULLPAGE]{figure}{\includegraphics[FULLPAGE]{example-image-a}}{caption1}{caption1a}
\listoffigures


\end{document}
```

Comment: Works for me. Please post an image of what you getting, using the example image, as well as a real image to compare.

Comment: I must mention I run the example with twoside=false

Comment: Yes, with twoside=false it works.

Comment: in this case I am forced to use the twoside=true option. Using the twoside=false or twoside=semi is not an option.